# How can I see what I have saved in iCloud

Tags: iphone

How can I see what's saved in my iCloud, and how can I upload my contacts from my iPhone 5s to iPad 4?

Comment: Do you have a specific type of data in mind?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iOS 8 there is iCloud Drive to see what is in your iCloud. First you'd need a Mac running Yosemite or a Windows computer with iCloud Drive on it.

Second, don't you have your contacts in iCloud or Google? You should be able to sync them across both of those devices...